# GET request in C without malloc

Tags: c, sockets, http

I need to recode `malloc` in C for a school project.
I'd like to send a GET request to a server in the `malloc` function. 
All the solutions I've tried,  produce a nasty infinite loop when loaded through `LD_PRELOAD` because they use `malloc`.

So my question is really simple: is there a way to make a send request using C, without using any of the `*alloc` functions? I don't care about what the server returns, I just want to send data.

Comment: Why you need `malloc`? You can use large-enough static array if malloc is evil.

Comment: Is your job to implement a `malloc` function or a HTTP library?  Both are full-time jobs but should be dealt with independently of each other.  Don't mix implementations of unrelated things.  Also I cannot imagine why on earth a `malloc` implementation would have to do a HTTP request.  Think about how awfully slow your program will run even if you manage to do that.

Comment: I've already implemented malloc, but i'd like to display the memory map on  a web application, sending the address and the allocated size

Comment: Of course there's a way. You can send from a local or static array, or even from a string literal. Similarly you can receive into a local or static array. `malloc()` is rarely used in association with either function.

Comment: All the socket function i've tried use malloc, do you know where can i find the documentation to do so ?

Comment: The real question is, "do you really want to document all calls to `malloc` (including OS calls), or just the calls that your program makes?" If it's just the calls in your program, I suggest that you use a name other than `malloc` for the memory allocation in your program.

Comment: I overload all the  `*alloc` function using a LD_PRELOAD variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing an HTTP transaction--which can take several seconds, and possibly fail, and calls lots of other library functions like malloc--inside your own malloc is never going to work.  If you want a documented malloc, the better way to do it is have a piece of code inside your malloc that puts the data to be documented in a queue--fast, no mess. Then, periodically, perhaps in a separate thread or some other slack time in the application, remove the data from the queue and post it.

A nice way to do this is Linux would be to write the data to an open pipe, and have a program on the other end of the pipe do the posting.

Comment: +1 for letting a different program handle the networking, although if the world is truly against him, then writing to the pipe will somehow result in a call to `malloc` ;-)

Comment: That's the problem ;) Even if i use shared memory segment in order to not do an infinite loop, <sys/shm.h>  use malloc.

Comment: @AbelChalier: That's only a problem if you insist on sending every single malloc request over (some) wire. Batch them up, and send them when you reach the batch limit or some short time period has passed. Then if the sending code calls malloc, it will just get batched into the next transmission.